# why use<bean:include instead of <jsp:include in struts?

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, struts

why use`<bean:include` instead of `<jsp:include` in struts?

Answer (score 2):

from the documentation for bean:include

Perform an internal dispatch to the specified application component (or external URL) and make the response data from that request available as a bean of type String. This tag has a function **similar to that of the standard jsp:include tag, except** that the response data is stored in a page scope attribute instead of being written to the output stream. If the current request is part of a session, the generated request for the include will also include the session identifier (and thus be part of the same session).

first hit on google

Comment: its only not clear if you dont know about scopes, and output streams

Answer (score 1):

bean:include works almost like jsp:include except that the result is stored in the page scope. This means that your code on the current page can access the results and manipulate it. [See this page](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/bean/include.html).

Comment: Can you illaborate please? What about jsp:include where is that stored?

Comment: jsp:include puts the output on the output buffer directly.